# Quick Edit ignores Content Type setting

Tags: 2013, content-type, quick-edit

I have created a new content type which inherits all columns from the default 'Task' content type. I changed the 'Assigned To' column in this new content type to be required. I created a new list where this is the only content type in it.

Unfortunately Quick Edit in this list does not respect this setting and so I'm able to create a new item without entering the required information. When using the 'EditForm.aspx' way everything is working as expected.

Am I missing something or is this some kind of bug related to the quick edit function?

Comment: Did you set the content type as default?

Comment: As it is the only content type in my list it also the default one. After creating one item using quick edit and looking at it in 'DispForm.aspx' I can see that the right content type has been used. Moreover I found another question here which describes the issue are little bit more in detail: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146672/require-that-this-column-contains-information-versus-setting-a-column-as-requi